# Explanation of the proof of Theorem 6.6 in Rudin's Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, distribution-theory

Everything that follows is from Rudin's *Functional Analysis*: $\def\L{\Lambda} \def\DDD{\mathcal{D}} \def\sbe{\subseteq} \def\W{\Omega} \def\RR{\mathbb{R}} \def\CC{\mathbb{C}} $

---

Below $\DDD$ is the space of test (smooth, compactly supported) functions from an open set $\Omega\sbe\RR^n$ to $\CC$. Such space is given a complete, unmetrizable topology $\tau$.

Similarly $\DDD_K$ is the space of test functions $\Omega\to\CC$ whose support lies in the compact set $K$. Each $\DDD_K$ has a Fréchet space topology $\tau_K$ which corresponds with the subspace topology under $\tau$.

**Theorem 6.6:** suppose $\L$ is a linear mapping of $\DDD$ into a lctvs $Y$. Then the following are equivalent:

a) $\L$ is continuous.

b) $\L$ is bounded.

c) If $\phi_i\to 0$ in $\DDD(\W)$, then $\L\phi_i\to0$ in $Y$.

d) The restriction of $\L$ to any $\DDD_K\sbe\DDD(\W)$ is continuous.

---

The proof shows a)$\implies$b)$\implies$c)$\implies$d)$\implies$a). I struggle to understand the steps b)$\implies$c) and d)$\implies$a):

b)$\implies$c): there is a compact subset $K\sbe\W$ that contains the support of every $\phi_i$, thus the $\phi_i$ are members of the subset $\DDD_K$ and $\phi_i\to 0$ holds in $\DDD_K$. The restriction of $\L$ to this $\DDD_K$ is bounded **(why?)** and since $\DDD_K$ is metrizable it follows that $\L\phi_i\to 0$ in $Y$.

d)$\implies$a): let $U$ be a convex balanced neighborhood of $0$ in $Y$, and put $V=\L^{-1}(U)$. Then $V$ is convex and balanced **(why?)**. Now $V$ is open if and only if $\DDD_K\cap V\in\tau_K$ for every compact $K\sbe \W$ **(I understand the only if implication only)**. This proves the equivalence of a) and d) **(how?)**.

Comment: "lctvs" = locally compact topological vector space?

Comment: @md2perpe locally _convex_ topological vector space. Thank you for asking; I should have clarified from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Let start with $(b) \to (c)$

As $\mathcal{D}_K$ is the subspace topology of $\mathcal{D}$ if $E$ is a bounded set in $\mathcal{D}_K$ than it is bounded in $\mathcal{D}$.

A linear map $\Lambda : \mathcal{D} \to Y$ between tvs is bounded if, for any $E$ bounded
$\Lambda(E)$ is bounded in $Y$.

Assume $\Lambda |_{\mathcal{D}_K}$ is not bounded, than there is $E$ bounded in $\mathcal{D}_K$

such that $\Lambda(E)$ is not bounded, but $E$ is bounded in $\mathcal{D}$, so  this contraddict condition $(b)$ and $\Lambda_{\mathcal{D}_K}$ is bounded

Now for $(d) \to (a)$.

The antimage of a linear map of a balanced set is balanced. Indeed, for any $a$ such that $|a|=1$ we have
$$
a \Lambda^{-1}(U)=\Lambda^{-1} (aU) \subseteq \Lambda^{-1}(U)
$$
The proof that antiimage of convex sets is convex is very similar. So $V$ is convex and balanced.

By theorem $6.5$ $(a)$ of the second edition of Rudin functional analysis you have that $V$ is open iif $V \cap D_K \in \tau_K$. So you have
$\Lambda^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\mathcal{D}$ iif $\Lambda^{-1}(D) \cap D_K$ is open in $\tau_K$

The first condition is the definition of continuity in $\mathcal{D}$ (i.e condition $(a)$).

The second condition is the definition of continuity in $\mathcal{D}_K$ (i.e condition $(d)$)

So they are equivalent